# Using LIMIT makes query much slower - optimiser moves ORDER BY

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, sql-execution-plan

I have the following query, which runs slowly:

```
SELECT l.track, r.rating
FROM library l LEFT JOIN rating r ON r.type='song' AND r.id=26452 AND r.value=CONCAT(l.name, ':', l.path)
WHERE l.id=26452 
ORDER BY title ASC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

`EXPLAIN` output:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref         | rows  | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | l     | NULL       | index | id,user_id    | title   | 2050    | NULL        | 14379 |     0.07 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | NULL       | ref   | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 66      | const,const |     2 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

With `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` that gives:

```
-> Limit: 20 row(s)  (cost=47313.37 rows=20) (actual time=60.414..1700.587 rows=20 loops=1)
    -> Nested loop left join  (cost=47313.37 rows=21) (actual time=60.411..1700.573 rows=20 loops=1)
        -> Filter: (l.id = 26452)  (cost=10.45 rows=11) (actual time=60.370..1699.964 rows=20 loops=1)
            -> Index scan on l using title  (cost=10.45 rows=14379) (actual time=0.141..1688.749 rows=120049 loops=1)
        -> Filter: (r.`value` = concat(l.`name`,':',l.`path`))  (cost=1.70 rows=2) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=0 loops=20)
            -> Index lookup on r using PRIMARY (id=26452, type='song')  (cost=1.70 rows=2) (actual time=0.016..0.018 rows=2 loops=20)
```

The thing that surprises me here is that the `ORDER BY` seems to be performed before the filtering and where criteria on `l.id`. As a result the actual rows processed is 120049 and it ends up performing an index scan. Note the rows estimate is actually quite accurate:

```
mysql> select count(*) from library where id=26452;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    15053 |
+----------+
```

If I remove the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` statements, the query is much faster:

```
-> Nested loop left join  (cost=80466.96 rows=55648) (actual time=128.144..193.327 rows=15053 loops=1)
    -> Sort: l.title  (cost=30383.76 rows=27824) (actual time=128.058..135.680 rows=15053 loops=1)
        -> Index lookup on l using user_id (id=26452)  (actual time=0.145..48.220 rows=15053 loops=1)
    -> Filter: (r.`value` = concat(l.`name`,':',l.`path`))  (cost=1.60 rows=2) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=15053)
        -> Index lookup on r using PRIMARY (id=26452, type='song')  (cost=1.60 rows=2) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=2 loops=15053)
```

Here, the sort runs much faster because it runs on far fewer rows.

##### Table definitions

```
CREATE TABLE `library` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `path` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `album` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `art` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `artist` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `band` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `composer` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `duration` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `genre` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `disc` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `track` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `year` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `format` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `bitrate` double NOT NULL,
  `filesize` int NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `edited` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `db_id` int NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE `rating` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `rating` int NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

ALTER TABLE `library`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`db_id`),
  ADD KEY `album` (`album`(191)),
  ADD KEY `artist` (`artist`(191)),
  ADD KEY `id` (`id`,`name`,`path`(191)),
  ADD KEY `genre` (`genre`(191)),
  ADD KEY `edited` (`edited`),
  ADD KEY `created` (`created`),
  ADD KEY `track` (`track`),
  ADD KEY `title` (`title`),
  ADD KEY `disc` (`disc`),
  ADD KEY `band` (`band`),
  ADD KEY `art` (`art`),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `library` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `all` (`album`,`artist`,`band`,`composer`,`genre`,`title`,`year`);

ALTER TABLE `rating`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`type`,`value`),
  ADD KEY `rating` (`rating`);
```

#### Sample data

```
INSERT INTO `library` VALUES (26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/An_Awesome_Wave/3-Tessellate.flac','An Awesome Wave','4f2737a092f58da88a17c05ea241cf28','alt-J','','','182.66666666667','Folk/Rock','Tessellate','','03','2012','flac',1101107.8248175,25141962,'2023-08-25 09:10:21','2023-08-25 09:10:21',88464632,'02588db1b1c7fb3f5847da6cd334338f'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/An_Awesome_Wave/2-(Interlude_1).flac','An Awesome Wave','4f2737a092f58da88a17c05ea241cf28','alt-J','','','72.08','Folk/Rock','(Interlude 1)','','02','2012','flac',1129123.0854606,10173399,'2023-08-25 09:10:21','2023-08-25 09:10:21',88464633,'5630f1fbae265a751a9e7b5512f1f97d'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/01 - Tangled Up In Blue.flac','Blood On The Tracks','','Bob Dylan','','','340.52','Folk & Rock','Tangled Up In Blue','','01','1975','flac',954125.50217315,40617131,'2023-08-25 09:10:23','2023-08-25 09:10:23',88464634,'bdc2868fdb8dfee2952adcb9120f450a'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/An_Awesome_Wave/1-Intro.flac','An Awesome Wave','4f2737a092f58da88a17c05ea241cf28','alt-J','','','157.81333333333','Folk/Rock','Intro','','01','2012','flac',1060156.809733,20913360,'2023-08-25 09:10:23','2023-08-25 09:10:23',88464635,'37cea636f5e7efb02f9978f98e993ba9'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/An_Awesome_Wave/4-Breezeblocks.flac','An Awesome Wave','4f2737a092f58da88a17c05ea241cf28','alt-J','','','227.08','Folk/Rock','Breezeblocks','','04','2012','flac',1042233.4683812,29583797,'2023-08-25 09:10:24','2023-08-25 09:10:24',88464636,'25102160c22f11c8c9a5fd359caa224c'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/An_Awesome_Wave/5-(Interlude_2).flac','An Awesome Wave','4f2737a092f58da88a17c05ea241cf28','alt-J','','','77.4','Folk/Rock','(Interlude 2)','','05','2012','flac',1110776.2273902,10746760,'2023-08-25 09:10:25','2023-08-25 09:10:25',88464637,'7564a31860d75727902dbcc5e6e0bf1f'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/An_Awesome_Wave/6-Something_Good.flac','An Awesome Wave','4f2737a092f58da88a17c05ea241cf28','alt-J','','','218.24','Folk/Rock','Something Good','','06','2012','flac',1031448.9369501,28137927,'2023-08-25 09:10:26','2023-08-25 09:10:26',88464638,'3cc973bc2422ee271a836be092941b7d'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/An_Awesome_Wave/8-Matilda.flac','An Awesome Wave','4f2737a092f58da88a17c05ea241cf28','alt-J','','','228.70666666667','Folk/Rock','Matilda','','08','2012','flac',967785.93831983,27667387,'2023-08-25 09:10:27','2023-08-25 09:10:27',88464639,'03ee261b3f42c8e449e886b471321bb2'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/An_Awesome_Wave/9-Ms.flac','An Awesome Wave','4f2737a092f58da88a17c05ea241cf28','alt-J','','','238.97333333333','Folk/Rock','Ms','','09','2012','flac',945418.52368465,28241227,'2023-08-25 09:10:28','2023-08-25 09:10:28',88464640,'3fba955cfe1b9f0ea804d3d5a4f5d524'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/An_Awesome_Wave/10-Fitzpleasure.flac','An Awesome Wave','4f2737a092f58da88a17c05ea241cf28','alt-J','','','219.4','Folk/Rock','Fitzpleasure','','10','2012','flac',999773.7101185,27418794,'2023-08-25 09:10:29','2023-08-25 09:10:29',88464641,'2f8f71f4aca1017ba9fc62e1d07daf21'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/An_Awesome_Wave/11-(Interlude_3).flac','An Awesome Wave','4f2737a092f58da88a17c05ea241cf28','alt-J','','','53.6','Folk/Rock','(Interlude 3)','','11','2012','flac',1183189.5522388,7927370,'2023-08-25 09:10:30','2023-08-25 09:10:30',88464642,'4cd364598a5ed7616ac3cb093cc18bfe'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/An_Awesome_Wave/12-Bloodflood.flac','An Awesome Wave','4f2737a092f58da88a17c05ea241cf28','alt-J','','','249.42666666667','Folk/Rock','Bloodflood','','12','2012','flac',859819.08376544,26807726,'2023-08-25 09:10:31','2023-08-25 09:10:31',88464643,'1028e8e524bfe6664cc6a021bf77b45f'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Arctic_Monkeys-Whatever_People_Say_I_Am,_That’s_What_I’m_Not/01-THE_VIEW_FROM_THE_AFTERNOON.ogg','Whatever People Say I Am, That’s What I’m Not','e0d2f8840d67eddb034f4f61f5e3b420','arctic monkeys','Arctic Monkeys','The Composer','218.13333333333','RAP','the view from the afternoon','','001','2006','ogg',117923.69193154,3289466,'2023-08-25 09:10:32','2023-08-25 09:10:32',88464644,'d9dfbf199ddcd964aed8ee66592780cb'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Arctic_Monkeys-Whatever_People_Say_I_Am,_That’s_What_I’m_Not/02-I_BET_YOU_LOOK_GOOD_ON_THE_DANCEFLOOR.ogg','Whatever People Say I Am, That’s What I’m Not','e0d2f8840d67eddb034f4f61f5e3b420','arctic monkeys','Arctic Monkeys','The Composer','173.68','RAP','i bet you look good on the dancefloor','','002','2006','ogg',117601.10548135,2625986,'2023-08-25 09:10:33','2023-08-25 09:10:33',88464645,'41ff5c5b8b03b5504dde219b3b39e569'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/An_Awesome_Wave/13-Taro_&_Handmade.flac','An Awesome Wave','4f2737a092f58da88a17c05ea241cf28','alt-J','','','761.62666666667','Folk/Rock','Taro & Handmade','','13','2012','flac',480492.07310668,45744447,'2023-08-25 09:10:33','2023-08-25 09:10:33',88464646,'c63a286070fb0ee400a03881ee169392'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Arctic_Monkeys-Whatever_People_Say_I_Am,_That’s_What_I’m_Not/03-FAKE_TALES_OF_SAN_FRANCISCO.ogg','Whatever People Say I Am, That’s What I’m Not','e0d2f8840d67eddb034f4f61f5e3b420','arctic monkeys','Arctic Monkeys','The Composer','177.94666666667','RAP','fake tales of san francisco','','003','2006','ogg',115716.24456766,2646270,'2023-08-25 09:10:33','2023-08-25 09:10:33',88464647,'2d203685f885d5df22e67387e74b3260'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Arctic_Monkeys-Whatever_People_Say_I_Am,_That’s_What_I’m_Not/04-DANCING_SHOES.ogg','Whatever People Say I Am, That’s What I’m Not','e0d2f8840d67eddb034f4f61f5e3b420','arctic monkeys','Arctic Monkeys','The Composer','141.13333333333','RAP','dancing shoes','','004','2006','ogg',119033.25460557,2173242,'2023-08-25 09:10:34','2023-08-25 09:10:34',88464648,'9f39fa0df2ea8bc4ee98841d089fe644'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Arctic_Monkeys-Whatever_People_Say_I_Am,_That’s_What_I’m_Not/05-YOU_PROBABLY_COULDN’T_SEE_FOR_THE_LIGHTS_BUT_YOU_WERE_STARING_STRAIGHT_AT_ME.ogg','Whatever People Say I Am, That’s What I’m Not','e0d2f8840d67eddb034f4f61f5e3b420','arctic monkeys','Arctic Monkeys','The Composer','130.81333333333','RAP','you probably couldn’t see for the lights but you were staring straight at me','[no title]','005','2006','ogg',115819.08062379,1966522,'2023-08-25 09:10:34','2023-08-25 09:10:34',88464649,'4b34d0b4433d52533678a10faa426291'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Arctic_Monkeys-Whatever_People_Say_I_Am,_That’s_What_I’m_Not/06-STILL_TAKE_YOU_HOME.ogg','Whatever People Say I Am, That’s What I’m Not','e0d2f8840d67eddb034f4f61f5e3b420','arctic monkeys','Arctic Monkeys','The Composer','173.66666666667','RAP','still take you home','[no title]','006','2006','ogg',119280.41458733,2662054,'2023-08-25 09:10:35','2023-08-25 09:10:35',88464650,'94fc01b32937c282561a4de953873c7b'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Arctic_Monkeys-Whatever_People_Say_I_Am,_That’s_What_I’m_Not/07-RIOT_VAN.ogg','Whatever People Say I Am, That’s What I’m Not','e0d2f8840d67eddb034f4f61f5e3b420','arctic monkeys','Arctic Monkeys','The Composer','134.93333333333','RAP','riot van','[no title]','007','2006','ogg',106505.39525692,1869000,'2023-08-25 09:10:35','2023-08-25 09:10:35',88464651,'fb3fd8d7c35f683348d57ddf5ec58cc7'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Arctic_Monkeys-Whatever_People_Say_I_Am,_That’s_What_I’m_Not/08-RED_LIGHT_INDICATES_DOORS_ARE_SECURED.ogg','Whatever People Say I Am, That’s What I’m Not','e0d2f8840d67eddb034f4f61f5e3b420','arctic monkeys','Arctic Monkeys','The Composer','143.62666666667','RAP','red light indicates doors are secured','[no title]','008','2006','ogg',119721.61158559,2220796,'2023-08-25 09:10:36','2023-08-25 09:10:36',88464652,'3f5623baa6cc34449df734e4f7691ebd'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Arctic_Monkeys-Whatever_People_Say_I_Am,_That’s_What_I’m_Not/09-MARDY_BUM.ogg','Whatever People Say I Am, That’s What I’m Not','e0d2f8840d67eddb034f4f61f5e3b420','arctic monkeys','Arctic Monkeys','The Composer','175.44','RAP','mardy bum','[no title]','009','2006','ogg',124005.38075695,2791511,'2023-08-25 09:10:36','2023-08-25 09:10:36',88464653,'a31ea1a457d9c05b0fd9990afb3f9e24'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Arctic_Monkeys-Whatever_People_Say_I_Am,_That’s_What_I’m_Not/10-PERHAPS_VAMPIRES_IS_A_BIT_STRONG_BUT….ogg','Whatever People Say I Am, That’s What I’m Not','e0d2f8840d67eddb034f4f61f5e3b420','arctic monkeys','Arctic Monkeys','The Composer','268.62666666667','RAP','perhaps vampires is a bit strong but…','[no title]','010','2006','ogg',113311.19273341,3876683,'2023-08-25 09:10:37','2023-08-25 09:10:37',88464654,'54818ba76bb68ad59597a11a50cd2178'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Arctic_Monkeys-Whatever_People_Say_I_Am,_That’s_What_I’m_Not/11-WHEN_THE_SUN_GOES_DOWN.ogg','Whatever People Say I Am, That’s What I’m Not','e0d2f8840d67eddb034f4f61f5e3b420','arctic monkeys','Arctic Monkeys','The Composer','200.01333333333','RAP','when the sun goes down','[no title]','011','2006','ogg',112391.70721952,2881341,'2023-08-25 09:10:37','2023-08-25 09:10:37',88464655,'399692b83aa1ce08df885bf84c65391d'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Arctic_Monkeys-Whatever_People_Say_I_Am,_That’s_What_I’m_Not/12-FROM_THE_RITZ_TO_THE_RUBBLE.ogg','Whatever People Say I Am, That’s What I’m Not','e0d2f8840d67eddb034f4f61f5e3b420','arctic monkeys','Arctic Monkeys','The Composer','193.42666666667','RAP','from the ritz to the rubble','[no title]','012','2006','ogg',113497.44261391,2816743,'2023-08-25 09:10:38','2023-08-25 09:10:38',88464656,'9b5e69c3e0b309ae648b1fe2785036ab'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Arctic_Monkeys-Whatever_People_Say_I_Am,_That’s_What_I’m_Not/13-A_CERTAIN_ROMANCE.ogg','Whatever People Say I Am, That’s What I’m Not','e0d2f8840d67eddb034f4f61f5e3b420','arctic monkeys','Arctic Monkeys','The Composer','331.2','RAP','a certain romance','[no title]','013','2006','ogg',121199.34782609,5089076,'2023-08-25 09:10:38','2023-08-25 09:10:38',88464657,'d383aa56bbe32ace2c6ea02a79d7e184'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian/The_Boy_with_the_Arab_Strap/01-It_Could_Have_Been_A_Brilliant_Career','The Boy with the Arab Strap','','Belle and Sebastian','','','143.0986875','Jazz','It Could Have Been A Brilliant','','1','1998','mp3',128000,2290125,'2023-08-25 09:10:38','2023-08-25 09:10:38',88464658,'689a04ae39d6e2289d18a315ff07ab4c'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian/The_Boy_with_the_Arab_Strap/02-Sleep_The_Clock_Around','The Boy with the Arab Strap','','Belle and Sebastian','','','298.18775','Jazz','Sleep The Clock Around','','2','1998','mp3',128000,4771549,'2023-08-25 09:10:39','2023-08-25 09:10:39',88464659,'eeb9ebfb2967d14e8db605e493606da5'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian/The_Boy_with_the_Arab_Strap/03-Is_It_Wicked_Not_To_Care','The Boy with the Arab Strap','','Belle and Sebastian','','','202.52725','','Is It Wicked Not To Care?','','3','1998','mp3',128000,3240982,'2023-08-25 09:10:39','2023-08-25 09:10:39',88464660,'0b6ba9b875f64ae04919e4e9c9b56080'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian/The_Boy_with_the_Arab_Strap/04-Ease_Your_Feet_In_The_Sea','The Boy with the Arab Strap','','Belle and Sebastian','','','215.7190625','Jazz','Ease Your Feet In The Sea','','4','1998','mp3',128000,3452051,'2023-08-25 09:10:40','2023-08-25 09:10:40',88464661,'e6002e2582996ac9959230ec0ef50f51'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian/The_Boy_with_the_Arab_Strap/05-A_Summer_Wasting','The Boy with the Arab Strap','','Belle and Sebastian','','','126.746','Jazz','A Summer Wasting','','5','1998','mp3',128000,2028482,'2023-08-25 09:10:41','2023-08-25 09:10:41',88464662,'c88f62d3568c5a4170734301defcc7f5'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian/The_Boy_with_the_Arab_Strap/07-A_Space_Boy_Dream','The Boy with the Arab Strap','','Belle and Sebastian','','','181.83825','Jazz','A Space Boy Dream','','7','1998','mp3',128000,2909958,'2023-08-25 09:10:41','2023-08-25 09:10:41',88464663,'cf777384e9092879c11cfcd4e217e235'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian/The_Boy_with_the_Arab_Strap/06-Seymour_Stein','The Boy with the Arab Strap','','Belle and Sebastian','','','282.88','','Seymour Stein','','6','1998','mp3',128000,4526625,'2023-08-25 09:10:41','2023-08-25 09:10:41',88464664,'f7f45234a56428c64f70c4ce375b1fe3'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian/The_Boy_with_the_Arab_Strap/08-Dirty_Dream_Number_Two','The Boy with the Arab Strap','','Belle and Sebastian','','','254.3541875','Jazz','Dirty Dream Number Two','','8','1998','mp3',128000,4070213,'2023-08-25 09:10:42','2023-08-25 09:10:42',88464665,'be127ad53e37d65ceaebd003e567e518'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian/The_Boy_with_the_Arab_Strap/09-The_Boy_With_The_Arab_Strap','The Boy with the Arab Strap','','Belle and Sebastian','','','314.1224375','Jazz','The Boy With The Arab Strap','','9','1998','mp3',128000,5026504,'2023-08-25 09:10:42','2023-08-25 09:10:42',88464666,'43794991b64e93dc21f1db0a59bd1a37'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian/The_Boy_with_the_Arab_Strap/10-Chickfactor','The Boy with the Arab Strap','','Belle and Sebastian','','','212.0619375','Jazz','Chickfactor','','10','1998','mp3',128000,3393537,'2023-08-25 09:10:42','2023-08-25 09:10:42',88464667,'d87b24c3b1bd335d4fd8ac545848b8fc'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian/The_Boy_with_the_Arab_Strap/11-Simple_Things','The Boy with the Arab Strap','','Belle and Sebastian','','','106.1093125','Jazz','Simple Things','','11','1998','mp3',128000,1698295,'2023-08-25 09:10:43','2023-08-25 09:10:43',88464668,'187e4798c715b05d15a98c5550d0e0e8'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian/The_Boy_with_the_Arab_Strap/12-The_Rollercoaster_Ride','The Boy with the Arab Strap','','Belle and Sebastian','','','396.591','Jazz','The Rollercoaster Ride','','12','1998','mp3',128000,6346001,'2023-08-25 09:10:44','2023-08-25 09:10:44',88464669,'ccaab1e16b3e842711ec5953a2c0e4a0'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian-If_You’re_Feeling_Sinister/01-THE_STARS_OF_TRACK_AND_FIELD.mp3','If You?re Feeling Sinister','827a059380f7248c012f960e4b831993','Belle & Sebastian','','','240.05725','Metal','the stars of track and field','','','1999','mp3',128000,3841044,'2023-08-25 09:10:45','2023-08-25 09:10:45',88464670,'f3555f8de94ab1bc3fee624e788f9b47'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian-If_You’re_Feeling_Sinister/02-SEEING_OTHER_PEOPLE.mp3','If You?re Feeling Sinister','827a059380f7248c012f960e4b831993','Belle & Sebastian','','','179.58375','Metal','seeing other people','','','1999','mp3',128000,2873468,'2023-08-25 09:10:46','2023-08-25 09:10:46',88464671,'eb0723f8989ad7be216bda053f1cfdab'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian-If_You’re_Feeling_Sinister/03-ME_AND_THE_MAJOR.mp3','If You?re Feeling Sinister','827a059380f7248c012f960e4b831993','Belle & Sebastian','','','183.42375','Metal','me and the major','','','1999','mp3',128000,2934908,'2023-08-25 09:10:48','2023-08-25 09:10:48',88464672,'7e786955514e383cd8d5f7eb46fa7cfc'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian-If_You’re_Feeling_Sinister/04-LIKE_DYLAN_IN_THE_MOVIES.mp3','If You?re Feeling Sinister','827a059380f7248c012f960e4b831993','Belle & Sebastian','','','206.256','Metal','like dylan in the movies','','','1999','mp3',128000,3300224,'2023-08-25 09:10:48','2023-08-25 09:10:48',88464673,'046d15f752789148bde9cc187f5b7abd'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian-If_You’re_Feeling_Sinister/05-THE_FOX_IN_THE_SNOW.mp3','If You?re Feeling Sinister','827a059380f7248c012f960e4b831993','Belle & Sebastian','','','202.6305625','Metal','the fox in the snow','','','1999','mp3',128000,3242217,'2023-08-25 09:10:49','2023-08-25 09:10:49',88464674,'1f43bbf907f7f4d4e48602a759a3a129'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian-If_You’re_Feeling_Sinister/06-GET_ME_AWAY_FROM_HERE,_I’M_DYING.mp3','If You?re Feeling Sinister','827a059380f7248c012f960e4b831993','Belle & Sebastian','','','156.9403125','Metal','Get Me Away from Here, I\'m Dying','','','1999','mp3',128000,2511239,'2023-08-25 09:10:50','2023-08-25 09:10:50',88464675,'34a8a674cd8b5c12e838b36fc7fd8d13'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian-If_You’re_Feeling_Sinister/07-IF_YOU\'RE_FEELING_SINISTER.mp3','If You?re Feeling Sinister','827a059380f7248c012f960e4b831993','Belle & Sebastian','','','272.6841875','Metal','if you\'re feeling sinister','','','1999','mp3',128000,4363075,'2023-08-25 09:10:51','2023-08-25 09:10:51',88464676,'09bf29295382c69d24c893a6279d50a2'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian-If_You’re_Feeling_Sinister/08-MAYFLY.mp3','If You?re Feeling Sinister','827a059380f7248c012f960e4b831993','Belle & Sebastian','','','173.6539375','Metal','mayfly','','','1999','mp3',128000,2778591,'2023-08-25 09:10:51','2023-08-25 09:10:51',88464677,'a9941169b98e2834edc4335381473e0f'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian-Tigermilk/01-The_State_I_Am_In.mp3','Tigermilk','2f3b0691ab79d244e9ca63349b2ea61f','Belle and Sebastian','','','298.0049','POP','the state i am in','','001','2008','mp3',160000,6312809,'2023-08-25 09:10:53','2023-08-25 09:10:53',88464678,'7b270e51c4c36cd2b7f1e5be06aea5c4'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian-If_You’re_Feeling_Sinister/09-THE_BOY_DONE_WRONG_AGAIN.mp3','If You?re Feeling Sinister','827a059380f7248c012f960e4b831993','Belle & Sebastian','','','209.23275','Metal','the boy done wrong again','','','1999','mp3',128000,3347852,'2023-08-25 09:10:53','2023-08-25 09:10:53',88464679,'f3877c2532077939751cf5a3ab174fe1'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian-If_You’re_Feeling_Sinister/10-JUDY_AND_THE_DREAM_OF_HORSES.mp3','If You?re Feeling Sinister','827a059380f7248c012f960e4b831993','Belle & Sebastian','','','173.07925','Metal','judy and the dream of horses','','','1999','mp3',128000,2769396,'2023-08-25 09:10:54','2023-08-25 09:10:54',88464680,'7c7cc03543c73c74b5456e71eafe1ac6'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian-Tigermilk/02-Expectations.mp3','Tigermilk','2f3b0691ab79d244e9ca63349b2ea61f','Belle and Sebastian','','','214.46535','POP','expectations','','002','2008','mp3',160000,4642013,'2023-08-25 09:10:54','2023-08-25 09:10:54',88464681,'4b9924b2a4c1dedd0ede0bbea152b61d'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian-Tigermilk/03-She’s_Losing_It.mp3','Tigermilk','2f3b0691ab79d244e9ca63349b2ea61f','Belle and Sebastian','','','142.31515','POP','she’s losing it','','003','2008','mp3',160000,3199029,'2023-08-25 09:10:54','2023-08-25 09:10:54',88464682,'04a8d2bfc20e424d843b6e3f7cfa548e'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/An_Awesome_Wave/7-Dissolve_Me.flac','An Awesome Wave','4f2737a092f58da88a17c05ea241cf28','alt-J','','','239.01333333333','Folk/Rock','Dissolve Me','','07','2012','flac',995182.53932835,29732737,'2023-08-25 09:10:55','2023-08-25 09:10:55',88464683,'b0b50adf7d09af5f8acf4b30dc882148'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian-Tigermilk/04-You’re_Just_a_Baby.mp3','Tigermilk','2f3b0691ab79d244e9ca63349b2ea61f','Belle and Sebastian','','','221.858','POP','you’re just a baby','','004','2008','mp3',160000,4789892,'2023-08-25 09:10:55','2023-08-25 09:10:55',88464684,'0633cb93da1bc442a2b9b88dcc75a4c2'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian-Tigermilk/05-Electronic_Renaissance.mp3','Tigermilk','2f3b0691ab79d244e9ca63349b2ea61f','Belle and Sebastian','','','290.92575','POP','electronic renaissance','','005','2008','mp3',160000,6171231,'2023-08-25 09:10:55','2023-08-25 09:10:55',88464685,'709a1752bff9d93fcc1ada2bae6e390d'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian-Tigermilk/06-I_Could_Be_Dreaming.mp3','Tigermilk','2f3b0691ab79d244e9ca63349b2ea61f','Belle and Sebastian','','','356.20575','POP','i could be dreaming','','006','2008','mp3',160000,7476828,'2023-08-25 09:10:56','2023-08-25 09:10:56',88464686,'89521ac172968c7cb9d664126b4b0b41'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian-Tigermilk/07-We_Rule_the_School.mp3','Tigermilk','2f3b0691ab79d244e9ca63349b2ea61f','Belle and Sebastian','','','207.36','POP','we rule the school','','007','2008','mp3',160000,4499912,'2023-08-25 09:10:56','2023-08-25 09:10:56',88464687,'911a8ba11f616eac57876ecd13436bfc'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian-Tigermilk/08-My_Wandering_Days_Are_Over.mp3','Tigermilk','2f3b0691ab79d244e9ca63349b2ea61f','Belle and Sebastian','','','325.8776','POP','my wandering days are over','','008','2008','mp3',160000,6870272,'2023-08-25 09:10:56','2023-08-25 09:10:56',88464688,'5a129c24101410804f962cb0900eff87'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian-Tigermilk/09-I_Don’t_Love_Anyone.mp3','Tigermilk','2f3b0691ab79d244e9ca63349b2ea61f','Belle and Sebastian','','','236.7739','POP','i don’t love anyone','','009','2008','mp3',160000,5088212,'2023-08-25 09:10:57','2023-08-25 09:10:57',88464689,'069addd2917588668cfec01a7f186e65'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Belle_and_Sebastian-Tigermilk/10-Mary_Jo.mp3','Tigermilk','2f3b0691ab79d244e9ca63349b2ea61f','Belle and Sebastian','','','209.6849','POP','mary jo','','010','2008','mp3',160000,4546399,'2023-08-25 09:10:57','2023-08-25 09:10:57',88464690,'0021f1e6af5e30ab079b423550e407e0'),(26452,'GDrive - scratch','A/test-libraries/scratch/Various_Artists-The_Best_Northern_Soul_All-Nighter..._Ever!/01-THE_SNAKE.flac','The Best Northern Soul All-Nighter... Ever!','a8621040922a456fd2c1d1a7772f5c71','Various Artists','','','209.32','R&B','the snake','2','001','2006','flac',989852.09248997,25899480,'2023-08-25 09:22:43','2023-08-25 09:22:43',88465142,'d6623134e50e2ffb5ad7c08322aa4a6f'),(26452,'SM','/Music/123abc/11 Oul Tani Eyh (Say It Again).m4a','Ah W Noss','181dccd2281663b6939a94c233d8c6cc','ن123','','','250.82195011338','','anb','','11','','quicktime',833671.15160966,26166908,'2023-09-16 13:49:53','2023-09-16 13:49:53',88818667,'0c317b6f8279e40ac6daef951977a8aa')
INSERT INTO `rating` VALUES (26452,'song','GDrive - scratch:A/test-libraries/scratch/Various_Artists-The_Best_Northern_Soul_All-Nighter..._Ever!/01-THE_SNAKE.flac',5),(26452,'song','SM:/Music/123abc/11 Oul Tani Eyh (Say It Again).m4a',5);
```

#### Expected results

```
+----------------------------------+--------+
| title                            | rating |
+----------------------------------+--------+
| (Interlude 1)                    |   NULL |
| (Interlude 2)                    |   NULL |
| (Interlude 3)                    |   NULL |
| a certain romance                |   NULL |
| A Space Boy Dream                |   NULL |
| A Summer Wasting                 |   NULL |
| anb                              |      5 |
| Bloodflood                       |   NULL |
| Breezeblocks                     |   NULL |
| Chickfactor                      |   NULL |
| dancing shoes                    |   NULL |
| Dirty Dream Number Two           |   NULL |
| Dissolve Me                      |   NULL |
| Ease Your Feet In The Sea        |   NULL |
| electronic renaissance           |   NULL |
| expectations                     |   NULL |
| fake tales of san francisco      |   NULL |
| Fitzpleasure                     |   NULL |
| from the ritz to the rubble      |   NULL |
| Get Me Away from Here, I'm Dying |   NULL |
+----------------------------------+--------+
```

How can I force the query optimiser to perform the sort on fewer rows?

Comment: Don't you have a column to join from `library`  except from `l.name`? You haven't included an on condition. Post table description to see the indexes

Comment: What's the point of the subquery when you aren't filtering in the outer query , or limiting the subquery ?

Comment: The subquery was an attempt to force the optimiser to get the matching rows first, before sorting.

Comment: Trust the optimizer.

Comment: Sorry - I should've posted the original query, I'll update it for simplicity.

Comment: > Don't you have a column to join from library except from l.name?

... No

Comment: You need an index on  `(id,song,value)` on `rating` table and `(id,title asc)` on `library`  table

Comment: Already got the `rating` one @ErgestBasha (assuming you mean `id,type,value` - `song` is the value, not the column). Can you explain why that composite index is needed for library? `title` is already a key as you can see (I've added the table definitions).

Comment: @DanGravell please try and change your query to `SELECT l.*, 
       r.rating
FROM library l 
LEFT JOIN rating r ON r.value=CONCAT(l.name, ':', l.path) 
WHERE l.id=26452 
AND r.id=26452
AND r.type='song'  
ORDER BY title ASC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0` . Keep in mind that integers are best in terms of performance on the join conditions

Comment: Yes - that is much faster and gives a result more like without the `LIMIT`. Post as an answer? I'd appreciate more of an explanation - you've changed it so the integer comparison is _not_ on the join condition - it's in the where criteria so I don't understand your reasoning.

Comment: It is a totally different query as the JOIN has been implicitly changed to INNER instead of LEFT, due to the criterion being in the WHERE clause. Maybe that is what you intended in the first place?

Comment: Ooof - sorry. This isn't right. There aren't always matches in the `rating` table, so I think it needs to be a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @ErgestBasha Sorry for premature triumphalism - but yeah, the `rating` rows are optional to `library` so the latest query suggestion you gave doesn't work - it only retrieves `library` rows that have a `rating`.

Comment: Have you tried moving the rating to a correlated subquery in the select list? I assume there can be at most one row matching in the rating table, or have I misunderstood your join? `SELECT l.*, (SELECT r.rating FROM rating r WHERE r.id = l.id AND r.type = 'song' AND r.value = CONCAT(l.name, ':', l.path)) AS rating
FROM library l
WHERE l.id=26452
ORDER BY title ASC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;`

Comment: @DanGravell please can you post some data example and expected result in text format ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha I added that... I also changed the query to just have one column from the `library` table to make the results easier to read. Apologies that the rest of the data is still in the example data - I can rewrite stripping it out if you like.

Comment: > _I assume there can be at most one row matching in the rating table, or have I misunderstood your join?_ - correct.

Comment: I should add, of course, that the sample data is not sufficient to replicate the query analysis, but SO won't allow the full data to be dumped.

Comment: How did you get on with the correlated subquery? As it will only attempt to join for the `LIMIT`ed result set, it should be much faster. As Ergest suggested earlier, you need to add an index on `(id, title)` - `id` for the WHERE clause and `title` for the sort. It will remove the need for the `filesort` operation.

Comment: You should not name a column `id` when it's not the table's ID. It really got me confused at first, because it looked like you wanted one library row joined with one rating row of which you knew the IDs. That made no sense, and then the execution plan and your explanations showed that the columns are just misnamed. What does the ID represent actually? And having to concatenate columns in order to join suggests an inappropriate database design you might want to change.

Comment: Sorry - the `id` represents a user and there are many rows for each id. I can understand why you think it's just one row. Agree about the design, but I'm working with what I have - it could be redesigned.

Comment: @user1191247 > _How did you get on with the correlated subquery?_ atm it doesn't appear to be a big improvement. Maybe I don't understand the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output, but I think the issue is that the work on `l.title` is being moved to before the filtering, thus it's working on more rows. Also... I thought `index scan` meant it wasn't a `filesort`... As above, there are already indexes on `title` and `id`. But not both of them together.

Comment: Read the EXPLAIN (not ANALYZE) output (or OPTIMIZER TRACE) and you will see the filesort (I suspect). The two single column indices cannot be used in the same way. Try the index! It should dramatically improve both the left join and the correlated subquery. Because the join is so expensive, I would expect the correlated subquery to be slightly more efficient, as it will only ever attempt the join for 20 rows, whereas the left join will join for all rows up to the current point (page 10 - 200 rows, page 100 - 2000 rows, etc). Check `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` cost estimate for page 500.

Comment: @user1191247 Thanks but I don't see the `filesort`: https://pastebin.com/irhm0YyZ

Comment: Depending on the number of rows in your table (explain suggests that 14,379 is just 0.07%), that could be even worse. It is returning all rows based on the order in the `title` index and then post filtering on the `id`. If you add the index suggested you should see 100% filtered and nothing in the Extra column. Just try it!

Comment: Will do ️ thanks again.

Comment: Experiment with it, to help your understanding. Try `FORCE INDEX (user_id)` and see what difference it makes with it filtering rows based on the index, instead of just sorting on the `title` index and then post filtering. You should then see a `filesort` but it should be 100% filtered. The MySQL docs have useful information on the [EXPLAIN Extra Information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-extra-information).

Comment: Thanks - the index appears to have fixed it: https://pastebin.com/w21ne0FM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
KEY `user_id` (`id`)
```

with

```
INDEX(id, title)
```

Normally one would say `r.id = l.id` instead of repeating the constant.  I don't think it makes any difference to the Optimizer.

If you know that `l` can be limited to 20 before looking at `r` (or vice versa), then a derived table containing the `LIMIT` will [probably] run must faster.

Comment: > _Or are you expecting NULL for track in some cases?_ yes - as per the expected output.

Comment: > _Normally one would say r.id = l.id instead of repeating the constant_ I agree - I think I was trying to ensure the joined table was as small as possible by directly filtering on the id.

Comment: The Optimizer is smart enough to see that both ids need that same value.

Comment: The index appears to have fixed it - thanks. Issued with column naming accepted, but would you like to remove the bit about left join?